# Sublime Text 2 - adjust letter-spacing

Tags: fonts, sublimetext2

Is there a way to adjust letter spacing in Sublime Text 2? Maybe snippets, plugins? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best idea to adjust letter spacing in Sublime Text 2 is to change font.

Comment: I was thinking to use some font editor, but this is too tricky at first sight. Actually, you can update sidebarings only in very simple and primitive font.

Comment: @yakunins yeah, font editing could be both problematic and difficult. I think that there are couple good fonts that have different letter spacing and you will be able to choose one that best suits you. I personally use font called 'Consolas'

Comment: I use Consolas too, but recently I have tried to use Segoe UI and found it useful only with large letter-spacing. I know this font is not monospaced, but my code doesn't have long lines at most :)

Answer (score 1):

@sebast26 is right. For example, `Droid Sans` has no letter spacing and seems not very good. But `Droid Sans Mono` has enough letter spacing.

[Here](https://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-font-family-courtesy-of-google-ascender) you can get it.